# Invalid Login attempt while accessing Netsuite using SuiteTalk(Web Service)?

Tags: soap, web-services, oauth, token

I am trying to get data from NS using WS. for that I'm using the following details in SoapUI:

[image]

WHEN I SEND THE request I get the following response :

[image]

Anyone had success with this or have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Also Have you any idea about how we can generate the signature if mine is incorrect!

Thank you for your Help!